# Python crashes with large numbers

Tags: python

I'm pretty new to Python, but I got this challenge to create a Fibonacci-generator recursively to get me going in the language. The problem is that if I find more than 3226/3227 numbers of Fibonacci, Python crashes. (Python 3)

Note: I have done a lot of programming in PHP, JavaScript, a little in VBA and a little in Java, but I'm completely new to Python. So if this is simply a matter of wrong data types or something, I am really sorry.

```
import sys
sys.setrecursionlimit(1000000000)

cache = dict()

 def fibonacci(n, arr = False):
    global cache

    if n == 0 or n == 1:
         r = n
    else:
        nVal1 = n - 1
        nVal2 = n - 2
        if (not nVal1 in cache):
            num1 = cache[nVal1] = fibonacci(nVal1, arr)
        else:
            num1 = cache[nVal1]
        if (not nVal2 in cache):
            num2 = cache[nVal2] = fibonacci(nVal2)
        else:
            num2 = cache[nVal2]

        r = num1 + num2


     if arr != False:
        arr.append(r)


    return r

fib = list()
# 3227 is max without generating a list.
# 3226 is max when generating a list.
fibonacci(3226, fib)
for x in fib: print(x)
```

What can I do to make it go further than this? I don't suppose it has run out of memory, since this runs on my slow i3-laptop on about two seconds..

Comment: If you need to increase the recursion limit, your implementation is probably not good (at least not in Python). Even with memoization (your cache), you can implement `fib` iteratively (with a `while` loop) instead of recursively (calling your own function).

Comment: @Tinctorius Yes, iteratively is easy enough, but it's not logically correct. But if I'm out of luck, then I'll call this a day and say the script is done. It was to learn some basic Python syntax after all..

Comment: Why is it logically incorrect?

Comment: @Tinctorius Well, it's not incorrect, but I believe the recursive way is a bit more logical correct in a theroetical sense. "I mean that in a practical sense, the iterative is probably the best one to generate huge numbers, but the recursive one is the theoretically most correct way of doing it. This is because Fibonacci is defined like a tree where the bottom branch is either 1 or 0. fib(15) = fib(14) + fib(13). Or x = 15, fib = fib(x-1) + fib(x-2) That's how I personally think is the most logical."

Comment: The (extended) iterative version and the recursive version are equivalent, and therefore equally correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reading the notes from [sys.setrecursionlimit](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.setrecursionlimit)

> The highest possible limit is platform-dependent. A user may need to
>   set the limit higher when she has a program that requires deep
>   recursion and a platform that supports a higher limit. This should be
>   done with care, because a too-high limit can lead to a crash.

I would implement fibo as so

```
def fib():
    a,b = 1,0
    while True:
        yield a
        b = a+b
        yield b
        a = a+b

fibs = fib()
fibo = [next(fibs) for i in xrange(100)]
```

Comment: Are you suggesting that Python cannot go further down that this?? How can I increase the memory so it can do this? This is disappointing.

Comment: @StudentofHogwarts you wouldn't implement this algorithm recursivly in python. You would use iteration.

Comment: So, if one should do it recursively one should be using C++ or similar?

Comment: @StudentofHogwarts Don't implement it recursively if that's not suitable for the language. Very few imperative languages can deal with this correctly. C++ is not one of them.

Comment: look for languages that support tail-call recursion optimization

Comment: @airza: most TCO won't save you here, because the recursive calls don't occur at the end. You want the compiler to turn this into an effectively iterative version, which requires strong reasoning skills, something most compilers lack (and imperative languages perhaps even forbid).

Answer (score 2):

I would guess that you are exceeding the max stack depth allowed by the python interpreter.  As you proceed further into new functions you will eventually blow through the amount of memory allocated by the python VM to fit the stack.

You can change http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html#sys.setrecursionlimit to a certain point but the maximum possible of depth is implementation defined.

Comment: Are you suggesting that Python cannot go further down that this?? How can I increase the memory so it can do this? This is disappointing.

Comment: Some languages (functional ones in particular) are designed to support very deep recursive function calls.  It is one well-known method of recursion (For and while loops being the other.)  In this case I would say that you are probably out of luck - Investigating the pythonic way of doing it (with memoizing smaller values or yield) might be an interesting challenge.

Comment: Well, doing it iteratively is easy, though it isn't logically correct.

Comment: @StudentofHogwarts Why is an iterative version not logically correct? It's equivalent when given infinite resources. The iterative version uses constant space, the recursive version uses linear space (linear to the ordinal of the Fibonacci number).

Comment: @Tinctorius I mean that in a practical sense, the iterative is probably the best one to generate huge numbers, but the recursive one is the theoretically most correct way of doing it. This is because Fibonacci is defined like a tree where the bottom branch is either 1 or 0. fib(15) = fib(14) + fib(13). Or x = 15, fib = fib(x-1) + fib(x-2) That's how I personally think is the most logical.

Comment: @StudentofHogwarts: You can calculate it bottom-up, and you can calculate it top-down. You can interpret the original recurrence relation given by Fibonacci in either way, and neither of them are more "logically correct" than the other. If your version is top-down, then the iterative version is bottom-up, starting with the zeroeth and the first Fibonacci number. To optimize it, you can observe that you'll only ever use the last two values, and therefore, you can perform the same calculation using only those values.

Comment: @Tinctorius Yes, I do see your point. It's probably correct based on the way you look at the problem. But as this was only to learn Python, I'm not looking to fix this by making the script from scratch. Yes, if I understood you correctly, that is exactly what I did with the cache. Thanks for the discussion! :)